# Solr still gives old data while faceting from the deleted documents

Tags: solr, solrj, facet, solrcloud, faceted-search

Solr gives old data while faceting from old deleted or updated documents.

For example we are doing faceting on name. name changes frequently for our application. When we index the document after changing the name we get both old name and new name in the search results. After digging more on this I got to know that Solr indexes are composed of segments (write once) and each segment contains set of documents. Whenever hard commit happens these segments will be closed and even if a document is deleted after that it will still have those documents (which will be marked as deleted). These documents will not be cleared immediately. It will not be displayed in the search result though, but somehow faceting is still able to access those data.

Optimizing fixed this issue. But we cannot perform this each time customer changes data on production. I tried below options and that did not work for me.

1) expungeDeletes.

Added this line below in solrconfig.xml

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxTime>30000</maxTime>
  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>

<!-- softAutoCommit is like autoCommit except it causes a
     'soft' commit which only ensures that changes are visible
     but does not ensure that data is synced to disk.  This is
     faster and more near-realtime friendly than a hard commit.
  -->

<autoSoftCommit>
  <maxTime>10000</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>

<commit waitSearcher="false" expungeDeletes="true"/>
```

2) Using TieredMergePolicyFactory might not help me as the threshold might not reach always and user will see old data during this time.

3) One more way of doing it is calling optimize() method which is exposed in solrj daily once. But not sure what impact this will have on performance.

Number of documents we index per server will be maximum 2M-3M.

Please suggest if there is any solution to this.

Let me know if more data needed.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `commit` like that in `solrconfig.xml`? That is a commit update message, which is usually sent to the `/update` endpoint, and not a configuration option. `expungeDeletes` also require at least 10% of the documents in a segment to be deleted to have any effect. Not sure if that's within your requirement.

Comment: Not sure if I can use commit like that. It is not working when I added it in config.xml but it worked for me when I used curl command. I think you are correct. But is there any other solution apart from expungeDeletes/optimize call.